# Concordance Java program not printing right output

Tags: java, debugging

I was wondering if someone can help with a bug I'm having in a project I'm working on. I'm currently working on a Concordance program that takes words and inserts them into an array. If the word is already there it will add 1 to the counter of the word. At the end it will display how many times a word was input to the program.

In the code below I have 3 Classes:

The 1st Class creates an object with 2 variables a String and an Int and a couple of methods.

```
public class Concordance
{

 private String word;//Stores a word
 private int counter = 0;//Stores how many times a word comes up.

/**
 * Constructor:
 *
 * Gives a default value to word if nothing is put in.
 */
public Concordance()
{
    word = "";
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * Takes users input and sets it equal to word.
 * Adds 1 to counter
 * 
 * @param String input
 */
public Concordance( String input )
{
    word = input;
    counter = 1;
}

/**
 * Adds a 1 to a word's counter
 */
public void addCounter()
{
    this.counter++;
}

/**
 * Returns the string of the object.
 * 
 * @return word
 */
public String getString()
{
    return word;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of times the word was put in.
 * 
 * @return counter
 */
public int getCount(){
    return counter;
}
}
```

The Second class which is the one I'm having issues with, creates an array of the objects in the 1st class and some methods that will check if the word is already in the array. If it is, it will add 1 to the counter of the word or else it will add the word to the end of the array. The insertWord() method is giving me a weird output. The conditional statement inside of the for loop does not seem to be working properly. When I insert Multiple words it will only recognize the 1st word multiple times but every word after that just gets put at the end of the array when it should just add the counter.

This Class Also has a method to print the array and a constructor.

```
public HashTable()
{
    Concordance temp = new Concordance();
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++ )
    {
        arrayWords[i] = temp;
    }
    arrayCounter = 0;
 }


    /**
     * insertWord()
     * 
     * Checks if the word is already in the array. 
     * If it is in the Array it will add 1 to the counter,
     * if not it will add it to the end of the array.
     * 
     * @param String word
     */
    public void insertWord( String word )
    {   
            for( int i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++ )
            {   
                System.out.println(i);
                /*Checks if the word is already in the array.
                *If it is,it will add 1 to the counter of the word
                * or else it will add the word to the end of the array.
                */
                if( word.toLowerCase() == arrayWords[i].getString() )
                {
                    System.out.println("Adding to Counter to word " + word );
                    arrayWords[i].addCounter();//Adds 1 to the counter of the word.
                    break;
                }
                else
                {   
                    System.out.println("Adding " + word +" to Array" );
                    Concordance temp = new Concordance(word);

                    //Adds the word at the end of the array
                    arrayWords[arrayCounter] = temp;
                    arrayCounter++;//Updates the counter array.
                    break;
                }//End of Conditional statement.
            }//End of for loop      
        }//End of insertWord method

        /**
         * printWords() method
         * 
         * It prints every Concordance object with their string and counter.
         */
        public void printWords()
        {
            System.out.print("\nprinting words\n");
            for( int i = 0; i < arrayCounter; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println( "The Word " + arrayWords[i].getString() + " comes up in the text " + arrayWords[i].getCount() + " times" );
            }
        } 
}//End of Hash Table Class.
```

The 3rd Class is just the main class I tested the output inserting multiple words to the Hash Table.

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main( String [] arg )
        {
            //Instantiates a Concordance object.
            Concordance c = new Concordance( "hello" );

            //Prints the string of the object.
            System.out.print(c.getString());
            //Prints the counter of the object.
            System.out.println(c.getCount());

            //Instantiates a hash table
            HashTable ht = new HashTable();

            //Inserts different values to the Hash Table
            ht.insertWord("hello");
            ht.insertWord("hello");
            ht.insertWord("there");
            ht.insertWord("how");
            ht.insertWord("hello");
            ht.insertWord("are");
            ht.insertWord("you");
            ht.insertWord("there");

            ht.printWords();
        }//end of static void
```

Here is what the output looks like:

> "The Word hello comes up in the text 4 times
>
> The Word idk comes up in the text 1 times
>
> The Word adcadc comes up in the text 1 times
>
> The Word idk comes up in the text 1 times
>
> The Word idk comes up in the text 1 times"

I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could have done it using `java.util.HashMap`where you could have taken a `HashMap<String,Integer> wordCountMap`but if you wish to do it using your own class then below points may help you.

You have created a class `HashTable` but you are not using the `hashing technique` so you should either change the class name or should modify the logic to use hashing. But for now lets proceed with the same class name and try to correct the existing logic.

In the constructor of the class `HashTable` you are creating a single Object of `Concordance` and assigning each cell with it. Modify it as below.

```
public HashTable()
{
    // create an Object of array of type Concordance. 
    //Let each cell reference to null.
    arrayWords = new Concordance[255]; 
    arrayCounter = 0;
}
```

Now lets try to fix the logic for insertion of words.

```
private int arrayCounter = 0;
public void insertWord(String word) {
    if(word == null){
        return;
    }
    boolean isWordPresent = false;
    // SCAN the whole array and see if the word is present in it else after
    // the loop ends then add new word 
    // Also you just need to check till 'arrayCounter' as it will always be equal to number of elements in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCounter; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        // equalsIgnoreCase in class java.lang.String returns null if
        // argument passed is Null, so extra check for arrayWords[i] ! =
        // null is not required
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayWords[i])) {
            arrayWords[i].addCounter();
            isWordPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // in case word is not found above then add it as a new word
    if (!isWordPresent) {
        System.out.println("Adding " + word + " to Array");
        arrayWords[arrayCounter++] = new Concordance(word);
    }
}
```

Now moving on to your `main` method, HashTable class creates the necessary objects of class Concordance. The Object you create of class Concordance in main method will not be used for the logic. Better remove below code.

```
       //Instantiates a Concordance object.
        Concordance c = new Concordance( "hello" );
        //Prints the string of the object.
        System.out.print(c.getString());
        //Prints the counter of the object.
        System.out.println(c.getCount());
```

Additional review Point which may be helpful to you in future.

1. Do not name your classes same as those provided by Java [ You have used HashTable]
2. A class, method, field or a local variable should justify the name. You have used the name HashTable but its actually not using Hashing so the name is misleading
3. Just put necessary comments and do not put excess of them. Use proper contextual names for your code entities so as the name itself is enough for the explanation.
4. Do not create unnecessary objects which are not to be used in your logic. They are not needed and add to the confusion while any other person will be looking at your code.
5. Keep the logic simple and if possible try it to be small. Keep you code easy to read and also easy to maintain.